# Oracle PLSQL evaluate variable in dynamic SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have the below code, which works fine because cols is evaluated before it's used on the second dynamic statement.

```
DECLARE
    vstr_aux_cols   CLOB;
    vstr_aux        CLOB;
    cols            CLOB;
BEGIN
    vstr_aux_cols := q'[
        SELECT
            LISTAGG('"'
                    || column_name
                    || '"', ',') WITHIN GROUP(
                ORDER BY
                    column_name
            )
        FROM
            all_tab_columns
        WHERE
            lower(table_name) = 'd_dialler_brut'
            AND column_name LIKE 'REASON%'
            ]'
    ;
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE vstr_aux_cols
    INTO cols;
    vstr_aux := q'[
                WITH aux AS (
                    SELECT
                        some columns
                    FROM
                        d_dialler_brut UNPIVOT ( v
                            FOR reason
                        IN ( ]'
                || cols
                || q'[ ) ) u
                    WHERE
                        condition
        ]';
    dbms_output.put_line(vstr_aux);
END;
```

However, if I try the below, it does not work because it first evaluates cols to blank and builds the vstr_aux with it empty. Is there a way to tweak the second code fragment to make it evaluate cols in vstr_aux after cols has been populated?

```
DECLARE
    vstr_aux_cols   CLOB;
    vstr_aux        CLOB;
    cols            CLOB;
BEGIN
    vstr_aux_cols := q'[
        SELECT
            LISTAGG('"'
                    || column_name
                    || '"', ',') WITHIN GROUP(
                ORDER BY
                    column_name
            )
        FROM
            all_tab_columns
        WHERE
            lower(table_name) = 'd_dialler_brut'
            AND column_name LIKE 'REASON%'
            ]'
    ;
    vstr_aux := q'[
                WITH aux AS (
                    SELECT
                        some columns
                    FROM
                        d_dialler_brut UNPIVOT ( v
                            FOR reason
                        IN ( ]'
                || cols
                || q'[ ) ) u
                    WHERE
                        condition
        ]';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE vstr_aux_cols
    INTO cols;
    dbms_output.put_line(vstr_aux);
END;
```

Comment: If you want the local variable `cols` to have a value when it is used to build a different string, you'd have to assign that value to the local variable before doing the string concatenation.  There are other ways to do that but since you haven't explained why the first approach is problematic, it's hard to guess whether any of them would actually be better for you.  You could take the code that assigns a value to `cols` from the first example, factor that out into a separate function, and then just call the function when you are assembling the later string, for example.

Comment: The function seems a good option. What would be the other ways to do it?

Comment: Again, without knowing what problem you have with the first approach, it's hard to guess what solutions might work for you.  You could build the string with a placeholder that you subsequently replace once the local variable `cols` is populated.  You could build the second string in a single pass rather than using the first string to build up the second.

Comment: There's no problem as such with the first approach. I was just hoping for some solution which could help me have all the execute immediates at the end of the code, it helps me a lot when debugging.